# Swift Result type conversion

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to swift and I am struggling with the new swift Result.
So I have this function:

```
enum LoginOption {
    case signInWithApple
    case emailAndPassword(email: String, password: String, completion: Result<Data, Error>)
}

// func 1:  wrapped with a ui tapped button event:
    private func emailAuthenticationTapped() {
login(with: .emailAndPassword(email: email, password: password, completion: {res in
                // to do 
            }))

// func 2: generic function that routes to the right signIn function based on signIn type:

func login(with loginOption: LoginOption) {
    switch loginOption {
        case let .emailAndPassword(email, password, completion):
               handleSignInWith(email: email, password: password, completion: (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void)

// func 3: main async func to handle signin
private func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
...
}
```

I m getting this error:

Cannot convert value of type '((Result<Data, Error>) -> Void).Type' to expected argument type '(Result<Data, Error>) -> Void'

Comment: Of what type is `completion ` in the enum case `.emailAndPassword`?

Comment: I updated the description, now it should be clearer

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it like this

```
 signInWith(email: email, password: password) { res in
    // to do 
 }
```

**OR**

```
signIn(email: email, password: password,completion: { res in
   // to do     
})
```

Comment: I think this should be when calling the login function like: 

```
login(with: .emailAndPassword(email: email, password: password, completion: {
                // to do
            })
```

Comment: Yes it's valid also but note with parameter ```password: password, completion: { res in  // to do }) ```

Comment: Inside the closure you can do a ‘switch res { ‘ with 2 cases: sucess(let data) and failure(let error). This capture each posible result

Comment: I updated the description, now it should be clearer

Answer (score 1):

You pass the type but you have to pass an instance.

The solution is quite easy: Pass the `completion` value of the enum case

```
func login(with loginOption: LoginOption) {
    switch loginOption {
        case let .emailAndPassword(email, password, completion):
               handleSignInWith(email: email, password: password, completion: completion)
```

And replace

```
enum LoginOption {
    case signInWithApple
    case emailAndPassword(email: String, password: String, completion: Result<Data, Error>)
}
```

with

```
enum LoginOption {
    case signInWithApple
    case emailAndPassword(email: String, password: String, completion: (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void)
}
```

Comment: Same error 
`Cannot convert value of type 'Result<Data, Error>' to expected argument type '(Result<Data, Error>) -> Void'`

Comment: @AAkrm change its declaration to `case emailAndPassword(email: String, password: String, completion: (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void)`